# How to fix form data in array that is not submitting properly

Tags: php

I'm building an admin form that allows other teams to update aspects of their own data so they don't have to call me to do it for them.

They update the data via checkboxes or text fields. There is also a requirement that they be able to edit multiple rows at once. So the form required them to select which rows they will be updating or have updated. so far so good.

My problem is thus: If the first record has one checkbox selected and the second record has 3 boxes checked, when the form is submitted and the data echoed back out, the first record shows 3 values and the second record shows 1 indicating that record 1 has somehow taken the values from record 2 for itself.  I know that's not the case but can't figure out why that data is not staying with record 2.

I've beat around this and searched and found numerous examples that should work but they are just using a single text field and not checkboxes.  So, I'm hoping someone here can help me sort it out.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['updateRecord'])) {
        // echo "Update Record Outer Check<br>";
        if ((strtolower($_POST['updateRecord']) == "update")) {
            foreach ($_POST['update'] as $key => $update) {
                $id = $_POST['id'][$key];
                $regOK = (
                    isset($_POST['regOK'][$key]) ?
                    $_POST['regOK'][$key] : false
                );
                $paidOK = (
                    isset($_POST['paidOK'][$key]) ?
                    $_POST['paidOK'][$key] : false
                );
                $ebdOK = (
                isset($_POST['ebdOK'][$key]) ?
                    $_POST['ebdOK'][$key] : false
                );
                $appOK = (
                isset($_POST['appOK'][$key]) ?
                    $_POST['appOK'][$key] : false
                );
                echo "RECORD ID: ".$id."<br>";
                echo " REG: ".$regOK."<br>";
                echo "PAID: ".$paidOK."<br>";
                echo " EBD: ".$ebdOK."<br>";
                echo " APP: ".$appOK."<br><br>";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<br><br>";
?>
<style type="text/css">
    th,td {text-align:center;}
</style>
<form action="" method="post" name="theForm">
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="resultsTable">
        <tr>
            <th>REG</th>
            <th>PAID</th>
            <th>EBD</th>
            <th>APP</th>
            <th>Update Record</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="regOK[]" id="regOK" value="1" checked></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="paidOK[]" id="paidOK" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ebdOK[]" id="ebdOK" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="appOK[]" id="appOK" value="1"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="test" name="update[]" id="update" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="updateRecord[]" id="updateRecord" value="update">
                <input type="hidden" name="id[]" id="id" value="1"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="regOK[]" id="regOK" value="1" checked></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="paidOK[]" id="paidOK" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ebdOK[]" id="ebdOK" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="appOK[]" id="appOK" value="1"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="test" name="update[]" id="update" value="2">
                <input type="hidden" name="updateRecord[]" id="updateRecord" value="update">
                <input type="hidden" name="id[]" id="id" value="2"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="regOK[]" id="regOK" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="paidOK[]" id="paidOK" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ebdOK[]" id="ebdOK" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="appOK[]" id="appOK" value="1"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="update[]" id="update" value="3">
                <input type="hidden" name="updateRecord" id="updateRecord" value="update">
                <input type="hidden" name="id[]" id="id" value="3"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="5" ><input type="submit" name="updateFormData" id="updateFormData" value="Update All Records"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The first two checkboxes are checked. Leave row 1 alone and check the second checkbox for record 2, select the update checkbox for the first two rows and then submit the form.  What I expect to see is:

RECORD ID: 1
REG: 1
PAID: 
EBD: 
APP:

RECORD ID: 2
REG: 1
PAID: 1
EBD: 
APP:

What I'm getting in this example is:
RECORD ID: 1
REG: 1
PAID: 1
EBD: 
APP:

RECORD ID: 2
REG: 1
PAID: 
EBD: 
APP:

You can see where the first record shows the data from row two.

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes are not included in the form. That is why you are getting undefined index error and why your output is incorrect. You need to find a way how to handle your checkboxes in a predictable manner. Maybe consider AJAX?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with PHP, but do HTML forms a lot. Is it really OK for the checkboxes to all have the same name and IDs? Wouldn't the received data show only the most recent input that way?

Comment: @Bman70 Only `updateRecord` is overwriting, but it is irrelevant in that code sample. The brackets in the name mean that it is a multiple choice input and PHP will treat it as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug in your code is indexing, handling form with index will solve it

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['updateRecord'])) {
        // echo "Update Record Outer Check<br>";
        if ((strtolower($_POST['updateRecord']) == "update")) {
            foreach ($_POST['update'] as $key => $update) {
                $id = $_POST['id'][$key];
                $regOK = (
                    isset($_POST['regOK'][$key]) ?
                    $_POST['regOK'][$key] : false
                );
                $paidOK = (
                    isset($_POST['paidOK'][$key]) ?
                    $_POST['paidOK'][$key] : false
                );
                $ebdOK = (
                isset($_POST['ebdOK'][$key]) ?
                    $_POST['ebdOK'][$key] : false
                );
                $appOK = (
                isset($_POST['appOK'][$key]) ?
                    $_POST['appOK'][$key] : false
                );
                echo "RECORD ID: ".$id."<br>";
                echo " REG: ".$regOK."<br>";
                echo "PAID: ".$paidOK."<br>";
                echo " EBD: ".$ebdOK."<br>";
                echo " APP: ".$appOK."<br><br>";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<br><br>";
?>
<style type="text/css">
    th,td {text-align:center;}
</style>
<form action="" method="post" name="theForm">
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="resultsTable">
        <tr>
            <th>REG</th>
            <th>PAID</th>
            <th>EBD</th>
            <th>APP</th>
            <th>Update Record</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="regOK[]" id="regOK" value="1" checked></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="paidOK[]" id="paidOK" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ebdOK[]" id="ebdOK" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="appOK[]" id="appOK" value="1"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="test" name="update[]" id="update" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="updateRecord[]" id="updateRecord" value="update">
                <input type="hidden" name="id[]" id="id" value="1"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="regOK[1]" id="regOK" value="1" checked></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="paidOK[1]" id="paidOK" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ebdOK[1]" id="ebdOK" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="appOK[1]" id="appOK" value="1"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="test" name="update[1]" id="update" value="2">
                <input type="hidden" name="updateRecord[1]" id="updateRecord" value="update">
                <input type="hidden" name="id[]" id="id" value="2"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="regOK[2]" id="regOK" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="paidOK[2]" id="paidOK" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="ebdOK[2]" id="ebdOK" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="appOK[2]" id="appOK" value="1"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="update[2]" id="update" value="3">
                <input type="hidden" name="updateRecord" id="updateRecord" value="update">
                <input type="hidden" name="id[]" id="id" value="3"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="5" ><input type="submit" name="updateFormData" id="updateFormData" value="Update All Records"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this. What i did here:

1. Preventing code coupling and **human mistake** by writing code just once and rendering the html inside a loop.
2. Assigning the `id` directly to the form data and making debug step easier
3. More readable and prettier code and clearing unnecessary lines

   ```
   <?php
       $ids = range(1, 3); // [1, 2, 3];
       $true = "true";
       $false = "false";

       if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
           foreach ($_POST['update'] as $id => $update) {
               if ($_POST['update'][$id]) {
                   $regOK = isset($_POST['regOK'][$id]) ? $true : $false;
                   $paidOK = isset($_POST['paidOK'][$id]) ? $true : $false;
                   $ebdOK = isset($_POST['ebdOK'][$id]) ? $true : $false;
                   $appOK = isset($_POST['appOK'][$id]) ? $true : $false;

                   echo "RECORD ID: ".$id."<br>";
                   echo " REG: ".$regOK."<br>";
                   echo "PAID: ".$paidOK."<br>";
                   echo " EBD: ".$ebdOK."<br>";
                   echo " APP: ".$appOK."<br><br>";
               }
           }
       }
       echo "<br><br>";
   ?>
   <style type="text/css">
       th,td {text-align:center;}
   </style>
   <form action="" method="post" name="theForm">
       <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="resultsTable">
           <tr>
               <th>REG</th>
               <th>PAID</th>
               <th>EBD</th>
               <th>APP</th>
               <th>Update Record</th>
           </tr>
           <?php foreach($ids as $id) { ?>
           <tr>
               <td><input type="checkbox" name="regOK[<?=$id?>]" id="regOK" value="1" checked></td>
               <td><input type="checkbox" name="paidOK[<?=$id?>]" id="paidOK" value="1"></td>
               <td><input type="checkbox" name="ebdOK[<?=$id?>]" id="ebdOK" value="1"></td>
               <td><input type="checkbox" name="appOK[<?=$id?>]" id="appOK" value="1"></td>
               <td><input type="checkbox" class="test" name="update[<?=$id?>]" id="update" value="1"></td>
           </tr>
           <?php } ?>
           <tr><td colspan="5" ><input type="submit" name="updateFormData" id="updateFormData" value="Update All Records"></td></tr>
       </table>
   </form>
   ```